# Creating a Dashboard of Claims based on date in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have df1 and df2 below:

**df1:**

```
df1 = [('2021-04-29', 'MN02') ,
           ('2021-04-30', 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-01', 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-02', 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-03', 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-04', 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-05', 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-06', 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-07', 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-08', 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-09', 'MN02')
            ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['Date', 'Group'])
```

and:

**df2:**

```
df2 =  [(100, '2021-04-29', 'NA', '2021-04-29', 'MN02'),
           (206, '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30' , 'MN02') ,
           (629, '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', 'MN02'),
           (4000, '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', '2021-04-30', 'MN02'),
           (4001, '2021-05-01', '2021-05-01', 'NA' , 'MN02'),
           (4002, '2021-05-01', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-01', 'MN02'),
           (4003, '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', 'MN02'),
           (4004, '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', 'MN02'),
           (4005, '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-06', 'MN02'),
           (4006, '2021-05-03', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-06', 'MN02'),
           (4007, '2021-05-04', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-04', 'MN02'),
           (4008, '2021-05-04', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-04', 'MN02')
            ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['ClaimID', 'New', 'Approved', 'Processed', 'Group'])
```

**Desired output:**

```
df3 = [('2021-04-29', 1, 0, 1, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-04-30', 3, 3, 3, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-01', 2, 2, 1, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-02', 0, 1, 0, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-03', 4, 5, 2, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-04', 2, 5, 2, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-05', 0, 3, 0, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-06', 0, 3, 2, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-07', 0, 1, 0, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-08', 0, 1, 0, 'MN02'),
           ('2021-05-09', 0, 1, 0, 'MN02')
            ]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3, columns=['Date', 'New', 'Approved', 'Processed', 'Group'])
```

A few conditions that this follows:

1. If a claim is approved and processed on the same day then both, approved and processed, in df3 should show the number of approved and processed on that day and then reset to 0 or the number of app/proc on the next day. For example, on 2021-04-30, there were 3 approved and processed on the same day in df2 so df3 shows 3 and 3, respectively and then they reset to the number app/proc on the next day.
2. If more are approved than processed on a certain day, the remaining approved should carry over to the next day. For example, on 2021-05-01 2 were approved but only 1 was processed. In df2, we can see that the claim was in fact never processed (NA) so that remainder of 1 should stay for the rest of df3.
3. If there are multiple approved claims and they are processed on different days then the claims processed later than the approved date should carry over until they reach the processed date. For example, 2 approved claims on 2021-05-03 are processed on the same day and 2 are process on 2021-05-06. Those 2 processed on 2021-05-06 should carry over until Approved reaches 2021-05-06.

Any help would be appreciated and I can clarify as needed.

Comment: is `5` in `('2021-05-03', 5, 2, 'MN02')` correct?

Comment: @MoRe yes, the logic is on 5/03 there are 4 new approved claims and 1 remainder from 5/01 (that stays for the rest of the dataset since it is never approved). Of the 5 claims on 5/03, 2 are processed on the same day. Thus a remainder of 3 for 5/04. But on 5/04 there are also 2 new approved claims so the 3 remainder plus the 2 new = 5 and only 2 are processed.

Comment: based on your explanation, `'2021-05-06'` approved must be 3, or I made a mistake?

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: @MoRe apologies, you are absolutely correct. I have edited my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def setter(series):
    res = series.value_counts().reset_index().replace('NA', np.nan).dropna()
    res['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(res['index'])
    return res.drop(columns='index')
approved = setter(df.Approved)
processed = setter(df.Processed)
data = pd.merge(approved, processed, on='Date', how='outer').fillna(0).sort_values('Date')
data = pd.merge(pd.to_datetime(df1.Date), data, on='Date', how='outer').fillna(0)# remove [1:]
datacum = data[['Approved','Processed']].cumsum()
# datacum = datacum[datacum.Approved != 0]
data['Approved'] += (datacum.Approved - datacum.Processed).shift().fillna(0)
# data.fillna(0)
```

output:

```
    Date        Approved    Processed
0   2021-04-29  0.0         1.0
1   2021-04-30  3.0         3.0
2   2021-05-01  2.0         1.0
3   2021-05-02  1.0         0.0
4   2021-05-03  5.0         2.0
5   2021-05-04  5.0         2.0
6   2021-05-05  3.0         0.0
7   2021-05-06  3.0         2.0
8   2021-05-07  1.0         0.0
9   2021-05-08  1.0         0.0
10  2021-05-09  1.0         0.0
```

Comment: hi! this works perfectly for the example I gave above. I slightly edited it to account for days where Approved is NA but processed is not. On these days a claim goes straight to processed rather than through approved then to processed. How can I can I account for that in the code you have above?

Comment: There is another column called "New" which I have not pictured here since I did not think it would affect the path of claims between approved and processed. Generally a claim will go from new to approved to processed. Sometimes a claim can jump from new straight to processed which is what we are seeing on 2021-04-29 (after I edited it).

Comment: I have added the new column to my example above.

Comment: @JohnTayson IIUC, you must use commented parts in edited

Comment: I am not entirely sure what that means. Sorry, still new to python and stack overflow

Comment: @JohnTayson which?

Comment: You stated "you must use commented parts in edited" and I am not sure what that means

Comment: @JohnTayson i mean uncomment `# datacum = datacum[datacum.Approved != 0]` and `# data.fillna(0)` and remove `[:1]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246416/discussion-between-john-tayson-and-more).